# Devops Implementation -CI CD

Tags: devops

I have my frontend in Angular. Backend in Java-Spring MVC. Do you recommend a separate docker image for both or a single composite image combining both to be deployed in production?

Answer (score 0):

If your front-end requires a separate process to run (and I read your input like it does), then you should have 2 separate images.

Rule of thumb - you can have only one main process per image. If you find yourself in a situation where you need more than one, you need to separate this into another image.